# When I use apt-get do I have to get packages from debian's 'buster' release?

Tags: raspbian-buster, debian

I am using CUPS on a raspberry PI as a print server.  The issue I have is that the packages via apt-get seem to be using the "Buster" v10 release of Debian.

Updates for softawre packages aren't back-ported constantly so this means that I am not on the later version of CUPS, which I need to be to troubleshoot an issue I have with it.

So aside from locally compiling, is there an easy way to resolve this ?

What is confusing to me is that I'm sure the SSD in this PI was created fairly recently just a few months back, and from what I understand Raspberry Pi OS isn't using Buster as a base now but instead 'Bullseye' ?  Ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Releases

Comment: run `lsb_release -a` to see what your pi is running

Comment: Nb. That the version from bullseye isn't the latest either: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/cups  Partially because RpiOS is currently behind Debian by a release (stable is v.12, bookworm).

Comment: @JaromandaX it reported:  Distributor ID: Raspbian, Description: Raspbian, NU/Linux 11 (bullseye), Release: 11, Codename:  bullseye... so I am running bullseye, yet why are packages being pulled for buster?

Comment: so, what makes you think *apt-get seem to be using the "Buster" v10 release of Debian*

Comment: I thought this because I googled the package version (2.3.3op2-3+deb11u2) and I think it took me to Buster subset of repositories on the Debian website.  So this was a red herring, I've done a 'sudo apt-cache policy' and can confirm it's setup with just Bullseye repository sources.   So it seems for now its a waiting game.